# TreeView stylescheets are not loaded correctly at the second time

Tags: asp.net, ajax, telerik, treeview

I have this problem with TreeView. At first time my treeview is good loaded with checkboxes and stylesheets. But at the second time the treeview has no styling. Have you any ideas why it's happened?

[image: Image at firstly time]
[image: Image at secondly time]

Comment: Is the treeview being made visible with an ajax request?

Comment: @MalvEarp, no. it visible with `asp:panel`